# Text style in google script TextItem title

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, fonts

I have written an app to automatically update an order form everytime an order is passed. Currently, the form consists in N Textitems, which titles are like:

> Product (remains : [number of remaining products])
>
> Product description

This is performed by the following lines :

```
var Products= wsStocks.getRange(1,1,wsStocks.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
var Description = wsStocks.getRange(1,2,wsStocks.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
var Qtys = wsStocks.getRange(1,3,wsStocks.getLastRow(),3).getValues();

for(j=0;j<Products.length;j++){
       Items[j].setTitle( `${Products[j][0]} (remains: ${Qtys[j][0]})`+ "\n" +`${Description[j][0]}`;
};
```

I would like to set a text style for this title : I want the information on the number of remaining products to be in italic, and the description to be in small size. But while I have found how to set the style for a Text variable, I can't find how to do this for a string used in the setTitle method ?

Answer (score 1):

You should get the `Range` of each item from the `Items` array first and then you should be able to change the `TextStyle` according to your needs by using the `setTextStyle()` method.

For customizing the text styles, you can create your own, something similar to this.

```
// italic text style
var style1 = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
    .setFontSize(14)
    .setItalic(true)
    .build();

// small size text style
var style2 = var style = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle();
    .setFontSize(11)
    .build();
```

Afterwards, for each element of the `Items` array, you should do this

```
for(j = 0; j < Products.length; j++) 
    sheet.getRange("RANGE_OF_Items[j]_ELEMENT").setTextStyle(style1); //or style2
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Class TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style);
- [Apps Script Range Class - setTextStyle(style)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#settextstylestyle).

Comment: Thank you. This does change the style of the spreadsheet cells, it does not change the text displayed in the form thourgh the .setTitle() method. I tried to change the getValues() by getTextRichValues(), but there again, the .setTitle() method will only work with a string and using .getText() losses information about the style...

Comment: Which form are you talking about exactly? Moreover, after you use the `setTitle()`, can you get the range of this element and then apply the `setTextStyle()`?

Comment: My aim is to have a styled text in the title of a TextItem element of a form. Once the title is set, getTitle() gives a string, not a range. However, I see that string *can* have a style, and that a styled string *can* be used as argument in setTitle ; but I have no clue how to set the style of a string. .bold() won't do, and neither will bold{} or .setBold(true) or .setFontWeight("bold")...

Comment: I understand now. However, if you are using the FormsApp, even when you have a TextItem, the methods available are [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item) - however, none of them offer you the possibility of changing the text style. So essentially the `Items` array you have is an array of Form items?